# Marmap create.buffer returns error even with correct arguments

Tags: r, geospatial

Function won't work and will raise error pointing out to the adehabitatMA dependency. My arguments are correct i.e., a 'bathy' object, a 2-col dataframe and radius in decimal degrees.

Comment: The example in the `create.buffer()` help page runs as expected on my end. Please, send a reproducible example so we can help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://github.com/ericpante/marmap/issues/30#issuecomment-1374752723), the problem is neither due to `marmap` nor `adehabitatMA` but rather to incompatible scales between your bathymetric grid and the very small size of the buffer you want to create: you can't have a buffer of less than 2 cells in diameter. Otherwise, it's called "a point", not a buffer.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I initially thought that the buffer could be created from the adjacent cells (even if it's just one cell in each direction!) since the radius I was using was at least greater than half the pixel size.